# SQL Server : update using three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update

I'm a bit paranoid and novice when it comes to update scripts. Will this script work in SQL Server 2014?

I have entries in the `country_code` column in the address table I'd like to update, these entries are supplier addresses; and I only need to update where the terrority is Finland (You'll see that from the last line).

The script:

```
USE %dbname%

UPDATE [address_backup]
SET [address_backup].[country_code] = 'FI'
FROM [dbo].[address_backup]
LEFT JOIN [supplier_table] --Joins the Address table with the Supplier table
     ON [address_backup].[addressid] = [supplier_table].[addressid]

LEFT JOIN [territory] --Join to the area table
     ON [supplier_table].[territoryid] = [territory].[territoryid]
WHERE 
    [supplier_table].[deleted] <> '1' --Not Deleted
    AND [territory].[territoryid] = '1000070' --Finland
```

I suspect it won't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing frnachisees_territory to be territory yes, it works; 
I would just check if all the JOINs are needed, since you use territoryid in the last one and then in the WHERE clause: could you avoid the last JOIN and use the supplier_table.territoryid for the WHERE?

EDIT: Possible script

```
USE %dbname%

UPDATE [address_backup]
SET [address_backup].[country_code] = 'FI'
FROM [dbo].[address_backup]
LEFT JOIN [supplier_table] --Joins the Address table with the Supplier table
     ON [address_backup].[addressid] = [supplier_table].[addressid]
WHERE 
    [supplier_table].[deleted] <> '1' --Not Deleted
    AND [supplier_table].[territoryid] = '1000070' --Finland
```

*I'd also swap LET JOIN with INNER JOIN as suggested by Juan Carlos Oropeza

Comment: Sound good. Also no need for `LEFT JOIN` a simple `INNER JOIN`   is what you want, because you arent updating the address without suppliers

Comment: Thank you two for both of your help :D

Comment: I have very slow line :)